# Please add creation date and last-seen date to the new Activity page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

The new profile page includes the "created" and "last seen" dates on the Profile view but not the Activity view.  That's fine for many users, but moderators generally need to focus on the Activity view, where this information is not present.  Can we *also* have these two items on the Activity page somewhere?

Investigating certain types of account interactions has become harder with the new design because of the extra clicks.  We have to click through to the Profile view to get that, but then usually go back to the Activity view for other stuff.

As a user I often want to see this too, but, ironically, as a user I'll see it on the first page I go to. As a moderator I definitely want to see the Activity page, not the Profile page -- so thanks for that change! -- but it does cost me these two bits of important information.

<sup>This is reposted (at Oded's request) from the bugs-and-feedback post for the new profile page.</sup>